# How to dynamically add a BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I added a `BottomNavigationView` programmatically but it's over the toolbar, how can I fix it?

```
 View parent = (View) container.getParent();
    coordinatorLayout = parent.findViewById(R.id.parent_container);
    bottomNavigationView = new BottomNavigationView(getContext());

    BottomNavigationView.LayoutParams params = new BottomNavigationView.LayoutParams(BottomNavigationView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, BottomNavigationView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);

    bottomNavigationView.setLayoutParams(params);
    bottomNavigationView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_navigation_main);

    coordinatorLayout.addView(bottomNavigationView, params);
```

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Please update your question with XML code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the view is added to coordinatorLayout, you should add CoordinatorLayoutParams for the BottomNavigationView.

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

    bottomNavigationView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: This could be a comment. If posted as an answer then write solution of this with code.